# Area 51 RSS feeds for proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51, feed

I was wondering if there are any RSS feeds for individual Area 51 proposals.I have signed up to one which may be closing and I was wondering if there a RSS feed for new questions or status updates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are RSS feeds, though I can't find a direct link in the proposal page itself.

To get the feed just type directly such an URL: `http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/proposal/[id here]`

For example, the feed for [Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) would be: http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/proposal/42810

The URL of each proposal contains its ID:

> [image]